# Executing custom generated JavaScript after resources JS file

Tags: opa, leaflet

I am trying to add a [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) map into my app and it requires adding some JS code **after** including Leaflet's CSS and JS. Opa server adds CSS in the `<head>` HTML node, but the `<script>` for the resource JS file is included after all the generated XHTML code. So, how to add the code for the map?

I took a look at the [GMaps API](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/blob/v2988/lib/stdlib/apis/gmaps/gmaps.opa) but it is hard to believe it is a good way to do it. The maps are added with the XHTML:

```
<script>
Xhtml.of_string_unsafe("some JS function loading the map");
</script>
```

Map loader written totally in JS as the string binds to onready, generates new javascript DOM element, and appends it to the end of the document.

Can I change the place where the JS file is included to the beginning of the document instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code that will let you define your own headers:

```
headers =
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/leaflet.js"></script>

Server.start(
   Server.http, {
     dispatch: function(_) {
       Resource.full_page(
         "Leaflet",
         <>Hello Leaflet</>, headers, {success},
         []
       )
     }
   }
)
```

Otherwise, if you want to append at the end, you can use :

[`Resource.register_external_js("/path/to/my/js")`](http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.core.web.resource/Resource/register_external_js)

[`Resource.register_external_css("/path/to/my/css")`](http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.core.web.resource/Resource/register_external_css)

This is useful is you need jQuery to be loaded first (jQuery being embed in all.js, at the end of the document).

Comment: It works, thank you :) Although, now I do not consider adding new script element at the end of the document such bad idea. What I did not like in GMaps API was using too much content_unsafe to inline JS.

Answer (score 0):

Although, as Fred pointed out, `leaflet.js` may be included easily in the header of the document, I stay with the JS for the map appended to the end of the document with:

```
function onready(_) {
  body = Dom.select_body();
  *body =+ <script>{Xhtml.of_string_unsafe(script)}</script>;
  void;
}
<div id="{map_id}" onready={function (_) Dom.bind(Dom.select_document(), {ready}, onready);void}></div>
```